# Many to Many Relationship, Correct Implementation?

Tags: sql, relational-database, database-schema

I am designing a database schema for storing Tenant and Address information. For the sake of normalization, and because I will be storing more than Tenant addresses in the Address table, I have made these two separate tables with a many-to-many relationship, and a "cross-reference" table. Also, stored in my cross-ref table is the AddressTypeID. I do this because the Address Types will be customizable in the software. This seems to be correct to me, is there room for improvement here?

[image: Many to many relationship schema]

Comment: This looks like you are on the right track. In general "contact" addresses can be of many different forms (fax#, email, etc.) as well as the simple format variations for postal and street addresses in different jurisdictions. Where are you headed with this?

Comment: I have a separate relationship for contact information (email, phone numbers, fax, etc.) As far as address format variations, I only need to store Address information for display purposes. The address will not need to be parsed for anything more than putting on the front of a mail envelope, so storing individual items (such as street number, street name, street type, etc.) is overkill, in my opinion. AddressType here is referring to [Work, Home, etc.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design looks good. Consider removing ssn to its own table with stricter privileges for privacy reasons. Lots of queries will need tenant; not many will need ssn.

Comment: That's why I love this place! Excellent idea!

Answer (score 0):

Your address table is not normalized. You should point to a foreign table for City, Zip, and perhaps County. You don't need to point to state as that can be derived from City or Zip.

You could also consider valid_from and valid_to (nullable) in Tenant Address